# Use rich text in QTableWidgetItem

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, richtext

Is there a way I can use rich text in `QTableWidgetItem`?

Currently I have this:

```
widgetItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
widgetText =  QtWidgets.QLabel("<b>foo bar</b>")
widgetLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetText)
widgetLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetFixedSize)
widget.setLayout(widgetLayout)
widgetItem.setSizeHint(widget.sizeHint())
self.tablewidget.setCellWidget(0, 0, widget)
self.tablewidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

But nothing shows it my table widget.

Comment: You could show how you have created `self.tablewidget`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a [`QTableWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html) you must set the number of rows and columns, for example:

```
self.tablewidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(2, 2, self)
```

Or we can set it later using the `setRowCount()` and `setColumnCount()` functions:

```
self.tablewidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self)
self.tablewidget.setRowCount(10)
self.tablewidget.setColumnCount(5)
```

But if you do not use the above form the widget will not be displayed, in your case the label.

Also it is not necessary to use QTableWidgetItem, as I show below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    tablewidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(4, 4)
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    widgetText =  QtWidgets.QLabel("<b>foo bar</b>")
    widgetLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetText)
    widgetLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetFixedSize)
    widget.setLayout(widgetLayout)
    tablewidget.setCellWidget(0, 0, widget)
    tablewidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
    tablewidget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]